# how can I fix a tripped breaker?

Tags: electrical

how do I fix a breaker that trips when the window ac is on?
I have tried unplugging other appliances . The breaker box is an old one.

Comment: Circuit breakers can go bad (trip too soon), and window AC units can also draw too much power (usually because they are very dirty or need freon or both). A tripping breaker may also be an indication of a loose (not tight) connection in the breaker box or wall plug.  Is this a regular household circuit? Or one dedicated for the air conditioner?  Is this a new problem for an existing unit, or did you just add the unit and plug it in somewhere?

Comment: added and plugged in

Comment: Then you are likely overloading the circuit.

Comment: What is the wattage rating on the unit?

Answer (score 2):

If it's an old A/C unit, replace it with new.  They are much more efficient (meaning: same BTU, much lower energy draw) and it'll pay for itself in energy savings.  I just saw a no-brand cheapie that was 8000 BTU for 5 amps.  The lower current draw means fewer or no breaker trips.

Even an old A/C is unlikely to trip the breaker alone.  Most likely it is the "last straw" on an already loaded circuit.  Next time it trips, thoroughly survey **what else** is on that breaker.  Research how much current or power each of those loads takes.  The best way is with a power meter like a $20 Kill-a-Watt.  Measure peak loads while the appliance is "on", e.g. A microwave while it's cooking, a laser printer while it's printing.

To be honest, most consumers have no clue how much energy appliances use.  This may be an eye opener.   The #1 surprise runs Microsoft Windows.  A lot of PCs are sold with 850 watt power supplies which can take as much as 1200 watts, though this depends on what the computer is doing.  The dead giveaway of a high-draw appliance is it makes a lot of heat.

And that especially matters if you are trying to air condition the space, it creates two electrical loads: first to run the appliance and make the heat, and then to run the A/C harder to remove the heat.  Reducing one reduces the other.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is more likely to be that you really are overloading the circuit...

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing the breaker, as sometimes they do go bad.

More likely, you're actually overloading the circuit. A common solution to this, is to run a dedicated circuit just for the air conditioner.

If there's room in the panel, it's fairly straightforward to do.

- Install a new breaker in the panel  (I recommend a 20 ampere single pole breaker).
- Pull appropriately sized conductors from the panel to the outlet (for 20 amperes, you'll need at least 12 AWG copper, unless the run is really long).
- Install a single 20 ampere receptacle near the air conditioner.

You could install an off colored receptacle  (red, gray, etc.), to make it obvious that this is not a typical general use receptacle.

Comment: I would rephrase that to drive home that a 20A breaker is not an option unless all the wire is 12 AWG.  Besides with many common window A/C's being 5A these days, even a dedicated 15A circuit is plenty.